# Where does the logic belong to respect SRP here?

Tags: design, single-responsibility

I'm working on a simple class to get a token from an API. As simple as it is, it has different aspects.

- A connection to the API is needed for this to work at least the first time. Credentials are stored in the code (security is not the subject).
- A token should not be fetched from the API more than once every 9 hours, thus it should be saved in a file when successfully fetched.
- If the file is too old, it needs to be generated again.

Now I'm thinking about doing four classes :

- **File** : responsible for creating, overwriting and returning the file.
- **Parser** : responsible for parsing a received file.
- **DateCheck** : responsible for checking whether the token is too old or not
- **Connection** : responsible for fetching the token through the API if needed

Now all these classes are fine (what do you think ?), but I obviously need a higher level class at some point to wrap all this logic and get the token with one simple call to this class.

Firstly there will be 4 dependencies, isn't that too much ?
Also, it will actually do many things and the reason why it is troublesome to me is because the unit tests are pretty big (15-30 lines) with all the mocking required, and most tests in successful projects code I've read are very small and simple to understand.

Is there something wrong with this reasoning, or is that the downfall the splitting up things that much ?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be making classic OOP design error : you are focusing on "things" instead of "behavior". In your case, there are three behaviors : `Fetching` the token, `Caching` the token and `Persisting` the token. There is also one nice abstraction : Because client shouldn't care where or how the token is received, it can use `Fetching` and `Caching` interchangeably.

So the design would look something like this : [image]

This way, client only uses the interface and doesn't care if token is cached or not. Also, you can introduce different ways how to fetch the token and still have caching available, because caching is just a decorator. I would also argue that there is no need for classes as you designed them, and just put the code inside the classes as in my design.

And if you want to get really fancy, you could introduce another abstraction for persisting the token, but that will needlesly complicate the design if you only have single persistence mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't quite understand the difference between ```Caching``` and ```Persisting``` in  your example. Also, does ```FetchTokenSource``` persist the Token itself, or does it delegate this **behavior** to ```CacheTokenSource``` ?

Comment: @SteveChamaillard Fetch only fetches and immediately returns the token. The Cache wraps around another token source and caches the value it returns. I created Persistence as class that has file saving and parsing logic and Caching as just the timing behavior. They could be part of single class or they could be separate.

Comment: I'd say that having a TokenfilePersistence is in fact not the cleanest design choice here. Go with a FilePersistence class instead. It should not know about a token, but should just store data into a file. The same goes for CacheTokenSource. I'd say you should have Cache, which does not know about what it is caching. Also I don't think sharing an interface here is a good solution. In fact you should expose only a single method in a single class (as it may take time to get the token), that gets the token. The other classes involved should not be exposes beyond that one class.

Comment: @Euphoric this makes a lot of sense. In the most basic way, there'd be only ```Persistence``` and ```Fetching```. This is very simple and feels right. Is having a class using those two classes fine then ?

Comment: @JonathanvandeVeen Your comment also makes a lot of sense, and both your comments can work together imo. I'm using a framework that has a ```Storage``` class that handles the filesystem (storing data into a file), should I extend it with a ```TokenFilePersistence``` or simply use it as is ? If I understood your point well, only ```FetchToken``` should be created, so no interface needed at any point ? I also have a ```Cache``` class available from my framework.

Comment: @Steve: The cleanest approach would be to create a TokenFetch to fetch the token and then create another class to put the pieces together. Maybe call it TokenProvider? This way each class has it's own responsibility.

Comment: @JonathanvandeVeen I disagree with your approach. It is practically same as Steve has in his question.

Comment: @Euphoric: It is really not. First of all responsibilities are divided differently. Second, the naming is quite different. It seems trivial, but makes a big difference in how a developer thinks about the code. Third, we just removed two classed from the implementation. And fourth, I added the thought of exposing a single entry point to the rest of the code, thus abstracting away the caching concern.

Comment: @JonathanvandeVeen Can you turn this into an answer? Also note, that there is one more class in OP's design. It is actually the "main" class. That does all the work and just uses the small ones. This is exactly what you are suggesting.

Comment: @Euphoric Absolutely, there's a "main" class in my mind that would contain logic to use both ```FetchTokenSource``` and ```TokenFilePersistence```. I don't know if this is the right way though, but I don't see any other way. I understand the point that both concepts are "Sourcing the token" in one way or another (it doesn't matter), but in practical there has to be some logic about these classes written somewhere to use them !

Comment: @SteveChamaillard That would be some form of startup configuration / dependency injection / factory logic. It would initialize proper way to "query for token" and then pass that to it's user.